# not showing red when company is expired/suspended

Tags: php

needing some help reviewing some code a previous developer did. this code is on various sites and all seem to be working except for one. This company is expired and not showing up red when doing a search.

```html
<?php

 //$today = date ('Y-m-d');
 //$expire_date = date ('Y-m-d', strtotime ( '-90 day' . $today));
 if($result){

  echo
   '<table class="" style="margin:0 0 !important;">
     <tr>
      <th class="center hide" style="width:5px!important;">X2Pay</th>
       <th class="header" ><a href="javascript:;" id="header_name"> Company</a></th>
       <th class="header"><a href="javascript:;" id="header_type">Type</th>
       <th class="header"><a href="javascript:;" id="header_country">Country</th>
       <th class="header"><a href="javascript:;" id="header_city">City</th>
       <th class="header"><a href="javascript:;" id="header_quality">Quality<br />&Risk</th>
     </tr>';

   foreach ($result as $row) { //echo $row->x2paystatus.'<br />';
  ?>
  <?php
       //if($row->x2paystatus == 'Active (Y)'){
       if($row->status == 'Active'){
        //echo $row->x2paystatus;
        $color = null;
       }else{
        $color = 'color:#dd2644;';
       }
       //echo $row->memberid;
       ?>

    <tr style="<?php echo $color;?>" class="<?php echo $row->HQ_Br;?>">
     <td class="center hide" style="vertical-align:middle;">
       <?php if(trim($row->x2paystatus) == 'Active (Y)'){?>
      <div style="border:0px solid red;">
       <a href="http://x2payonline.com" target="_blank">
        <img class="" style="width:25px;" src="<?php echo $wp_upload_dir.'/2015/10/x2pay.png';?>" alt="">
       </a>
      </div>
     <?php } ?>
      </td>

      <td>
       <a href="<?php echo site_url('member-area/view-company-profile?id='.$row->memberid);?>">
       <?php echo $row->membername;?></a>
      </td>

      <td class="" ><?php echo $row->HQ_Br;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->country;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->city;?></td>
      <td class="center hide">
       <span class="tooltip tooltip-effect-5">
     <a class="tooltiplink" href="<?php echo site_url('member-area/view-company-profile?id='.$row->memberid);?>"><span class="tooltip-item">View</span></a>
     <span class="tooltip-content clearfix">
      <span class="tooltip-text">
       <p>Tier : <?php if($row->tierlevel){echo $row->tierlevel;}else{echo '-';}?></p>
       <p>Risk level : <?php if($row->quality_risk_level){echo $row->quality_risk_level;}else{ echo '8'; }?></p>
       <p class="img">
        <?php
         for($i=1;$i<=$row->quality_risk_startrating;$i++)
         {
          echo '<img style="width:16px!important;height:16px!important;margin:0;" src="'.$img_dir.'star-active.png" />';
         }
        ?>
       </p><br /><br />

        <p>Since  : <?php echo date('Y', strtotime($row->enrollment_date));?></p>
      </span>
     </span>
    </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

  <?php
   }
   echo '</table>';
  }else{
   //echo 'No result';
  }
?>
```

Comment: You need to change status by doing  an update on the record. Is any of the expired companies showing up as red???

Comment: yes, i checked on other sites and this particular company does show up red. I also reviewed to make sure this company is expired in our records. I just find it odd it does not show on one website

Comment: Oh ok so the results are on many sites. Can you post url? I bet it is a css override!

Comment: what is company name? Or how do I view record?

Comment: NIELSEN FREIGHT....

Comment: I cannot view companies without user profile

Comment: Why is this tagged `javascript`? There's no Javascript anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is rendering red on other sites that means this is clearly a css styling rule override which is preventing it from rendering red. I'd look into the style sheet for that site and see if background has tr css rule with the `!important` declaration. Many times when your dealing with tables people write css rules and accidentally override css on other tables unintentionally.

I would use **F12** on table element and see what css rules are being applied to that element on the site in question.

Comment: thanks, I will look at that. I figured this would be something simple

Comment: Np. please mark as correct if you find this is problem.